# What are the instruments in a panel p-var? (vector autoregression)

Tags: vector-auto-regression

So, I am following Abrigo Love (2015) and I want to write a Matlab code to produce the estimate of a panel VAR (I do know that there is a STATA code already done, but I am trying something different, so I need to create it from scratch).
The main model is:
   $$ \Delta Y_{it} = \Delta \bar{ Y_{it}} A + \Delta e_{it} \\
\Delta Y_{it} = [\Delta y_{it}^1 ... \Delta y_{it}^k] \\
\Delta \bar{ Y_{it}} =  [\Delta Y_{it-1} ... \Delta Y_{it-p}\Delta X_{it}] \\
\Delta e_{it} = [\Delta e_{it}^1,...,\Delta e_{it}^k] \\
A^T =[A_1^T, ... ,A_p^T, B^T] $$

and with $\Delta m_{it} $ either $ = m_{it} - m_{it-1} $ or $ = (m_{it} - \bar  m_{it-1} ) \sqrt{( T_{it}/ T_{it} +1)}$. Notice the Vectors are row-vectors and not column-vectors (as some of us are used to).

Then Abrigo/Love say one should stack observations over panels and then over time (which is clear to me) and get the GMM estimator by (the usual GMM estimator) (:

$$ A = ( \Delta \bar Y^T Z \hat W Z^T \Delta \bar Y)^{-1} (\Delta \bar Y^T Z \hat W Z^T \Delta Y ) $$

Here is the question: how to write $\Delta Y$, $\Delta \bar Y$, and $ Z$ in Matlab? I know Z should be a bunch of instruments, but where do I get them and how should I stack it in this notation?

Furthermore, if I wanted Z (the instruments) either to include or to be lags of $\Delta Y$, how should I do it?

I need to know how to put it in Matlab, so some answer in matrix-vector notation would be very helpful.

Comment: This is very specialized. You will have more answers by posting your question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/statistics

Comment: Thanks, will do!